# Firestore - Is there any charges for R&W operations performed using ADMIN SDK

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using firestore ADMIN SDK for data backup-restore. Is there any charges for operations like read and write when performed using ADMIN SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly the same charges than you would have by using the Client SDKs to read and write from/to Firestore.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Is charges are also applied when we read the data in Firebase console?

Comment: "Is charges are also applied when we read the data in Firebase console": Yes.